# How To Add Javascript Reference to HTML when Rendering a PHP object?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

We use a lot of PHP modules here to create objects that are used to build our web pages.

We have modules for:

- Anchor (ahref)
- Button
- CheckBox
- ComboBox
- DateTime
- Email
- Label
- Note
- Password
- Phone
- RadioButton
- RichTextArea
- SubmitButton
- Text (TextBox)

Each object is converted to HTML for the PHP by calling the item's `render()` method; however, none of the modules contain javascript.

I want to create a **Contact Block** module that will contain standard contact elements (name, address, city, state, phone, email, blah-blah-blah).

I have created a javascript file with my jquery syntax to validate the controls in my **Contact Block**, but I cannot get my  tag placed in the HTML's  section.

Is there still a way to get the javascript to work?

```
public function render() {
  $output = '<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/js/ContactBlock.js"></script>\n';
  // other code ... $output .= '<fieldset><legend>'.$this->groupName.'</legend>\n';
  return($output);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

> snipped to avoid copyright infringement

This may be too simplified, but basically it renders the HTML to the browser.

I want to add my **Contact Block** elements with javascript to validate fields.

The line `$form = new HTMLForm('Blank Page')` creates the HTML page with the  tag already in it.

Is there a way for me to add my **Contact Block** with validating javascript if the  tag has already been closed?

**UPDATE 2:**

> snipped to avoid copyright infringement

Comment: Change `return` to `echo`...

Comment: Unless he's calling this function and echoing the return value

Comment: I think we need a little more code here. Are you loading jQuery? Is this being rendered to the page before jQuery is loaded? Are you sure that you're calling the JS function in order to fire it?

Comment: Hang on. I'll add some details.

Comment: Can you demonstrate an example for us such as how would you create a `Button`?

Comment: I updated. Sorry, but I used a Label. That should give you a general idea on how my company has its framework set up.

Comment: I am extremely green to PHP and jQuery. The technique this company uses compounds the difficulty I have in learning how to code.

Comment: Would you be able to find the `PhpLabel` class/function and paste it here?

Comment: Done. It extends `BasicHTMLEntity`, though. Do you need that one? Like I said, very steep learning curve for a green PHP developer.

Comment: I totally understand, I just wouldn't want to provide you with an answer that doesn't go along with the flow of your framework =)

Comment: I added the `BasicHTMLEntity` class, but I will need to remove that shortly. There could be proprietary issues with posting that. Let me know once you have what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do it.

First, create this class:

```
<?php

//Named this way so you can make any element tag
class PhpFreeElement extends BasicHTMLEntity {

    private $strong = false;

    public function __construct($tag_type, $element_name) {

        // Set element type
        $this->setElementType( $tag_type );

        // Specify behavior of element value
        $this->entity_value_as_content = true;

        // Specify default attributes
        if ( !empty( $name ) ) {
            $this->attr('name', $element_name);
            $this->attr('id', $element_name);
        }
    }

    public function setAttribute($name, $value)
    {
        $this->attr( $name, $value );
    }


    public function render(){

        // Open element
        $output = "<{$this->getElementType()}{$this->renderAttributes()}";

        //Add the value if any
        $output .= ">{$this->getValue()}";

        // Close element (This is not always correct. Some tags are self closing)
        $output .= "</{$this->getElementType()}>";

        // Return rendered object
        return($output);
    }
}

?>
```

Then you create it like this:

```
//Create script tag
$script = new PhpFreeElement('script', '');

//Set the script source
$script->setAttribute( "src", "/lib/js/ContactBlock.js" );
```

Comment: Interesting approach, and it fits in with what we currently use. I'm certainly going to try this method, too. Note: I'm going to remove the classes that I pasted in the **Update** sections because they could be proprietary. If this is a **Well Known PHP Model**, let me know and I'll link that in or reference it by name so others will now how you got to this end result! :)

Comment: @jp2code Can you mark this as the answer? I would also check on the proprietaryness of that code because if it's open source or allowed to be posted here (it's pretty simply code) it would be helpful to understanding this.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your framework to the full extent I would have to say that you probably need a `PhpJsScript` class:

```
<?php

    class PhpJsScript extends BasicHTMLEntity {

        public function __construct($url) {

            // Set element type
            $this->setElementType('script');

            // Specify behavior of element value
            $this->entity_value_as_content = true;

            // Specify default attributes
            $this->attr('type', 'text/javascript');
            $this->attr('src', $url);
        }

        public function render(){
            // Open element
            $output = "<{$this->getElementType()}{$this->renderAttributes()}";

            // Close element
            $output .= "</{$this->getElementType()}>";

            // Return rendered object
            return($output);
        }
    }

?>
```

So now I think you can call it with:

```
$script = new PhpJsScript('/lib/js/ContactBlock.js');
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to remove the classes now that I worry could be proprietary. If this is a well known type of model, let me know and I'll link that in so others will now how you got to this end result! :)

Comment: I don't have a name for it but I pretty much re-wrote the `PhpLabel` class so that it creates a properly formed `<script>` tag instead

Comment: Also, if you are worried about leaked code then I should inform you of the Edit history that StackOverflow tracks incredibly well. Under your Post you should see a link that says `Edited X minutes/days/months ago`

Comment: But overall the stuff you showed isn't enough for me to learn something I didn't already know =)